# Explaining behavior of methods & variables with same names & other properties in ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, hash, methods, scalar

I am just trying to *understand* the behaviour of the `destroy` method in the following code:

UPDATE : Please note my intention is to understand the behaviour, not the immediate solution for assigning nil to the variable.

```
    def conf
      @conf ||= { 'foo' => { 'bar' => 'baz' } }
    end

    def destroy
      conf = nil
    end

    def change
      conf['foo']['bar'] = 'meh'
    end

    def add
      conf['foo']['abc'] = 'moo'
    end
```

Here is the output for invoking the `add` method:

```
    add
    pp conf
    # {"foo"=>{"bar"=>"baz", "abc"=>"moo"}}
```

`change` method

```
   change
   pp conf
   # {"foo"=>{"bar"=>"meh"}}
```

`destroy` method

```
   destroy
   pp conf
   # {"foo"=>{"bar"=>"baz"}}
```

So, why doesn't `destroy` result in `conf` having `nil` ?

Another related snippet, this time with a scalar not a hash:

```
    def foo
      @foo ||= "bar"
    end

    def destroyfoo
      foo = nil
    end

    def changefoo
      foo = "baz"
    end
```

Result when calling `changefoo` and `destroyfoo` both:

```
    destroyfoo
    puts foo
    # "bar"
```

...

```
    changefoo
    puts foo
    # "bar"
```

Any pointers on what might be happening would be useful in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `destroy`, `destroyfoo` and `changefoo` methods are all just assigning to a local variable and do not result in a call to the accessor method.

The reason that the `change` method works is because `conf['foo']['bar'] = 'meh'` is a call to the `conf` method to get `@conf`, then a call to the `[]` method on the object returned, then a call to the `[]=` method on the first level hash. Likewise for `add`.

This is different to a direct assignment like `conf =`

Also, for completeness, note that even if you'd created an attr writer for `@conf` (either using `attr_writer` or by writing a `conf=` method yourself) then a line like `conf = nil` would still be referring to a local variable and wouldn't call your method. You'd need to use `self.conf=` in order to disambiguate.

Comment: Small question just out of curiosity - how does the parser determine that in conf['foo']['bar'] it wants to call the method ? Due to the absence of any another local conf hash in the scope of say, the change method ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have to be a hash. Ruby would first look for an existing local variable called `conf` and if one wasn't found then it would try to resolve `conf` as a method.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your `destroy` method is creating a variable named `conf`. Ruby is able to tell what is a method and what is a variable based on how you call it.

```
irb> puts "Lincoln"
Lincoln
irb> puts = "Washington"
irb> puts "Polk"
Polk
irb> puts puts 
Washington
```

What happened here is there is a method called `puts` and there is a variable called `puts`. Ruby determines which you are trying to use based on how you are calling it. In the last example, the left `puts` is the method call while the right `puts` is the variable.

Note that the variable `destroy` creates will drop out of scope once the method block is done executing. So, in your case, trying to call `conf` anytime outside of a method (on the main scope) will be a call to the method.